# Django get_queryset returns 500 instead of 404

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here is my view:

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = SampleSerializer
      queryset = Sample.objects.all()

      def get_queryset(self):
          queryset = self.queryset
          test_code = self.request.query_params.get('test_code', None)
          if test_code is not None:
             queryset = queryset.filter(test__test_code=test_code)
          return queryset
```

Here is my Model:

```
class Sampe(models.Model):
      test = models.OneToOneField(Test, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      # few more fields- not so important
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      test_code = serializers.CharField(source='test.test_code')

      class Meta:
           model = Sample
           fields = '__all__'
```

This works when I hit /api/sample?test_code="existing_param"
So when I do /api/sample?test_code="Not_Existing_param", I was expecting it should throw me 404 instead, it throws 500 Test matching query does not exist. Really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the problem is that the function will raise an error, and the web server can not really *interpret* what caused this error, so it is more accurate to raise a 500 in general, than a 404.

But what you can do is use a [**`get_list_or_404`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) which acts like a `get_object_or_404`, but then with a `.filter(..)` instead of a `.get(..)`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = SampleSerializer
      queryset = Sample.objects.all()

      def get_queryset(self):
          queryset = self.queryset
          test_code = self.request.query_params.get('test_code', None)
          if test_code is not None:
             queryset = get_list_or_404(queryset, test__test_code=test_code)
          return queryset
```

This will thus filter the queryset, and raise a 404 exception in case the resulting queryset turns out to be empty. In case you *chain* filters together, it is sufficient to do this on the last element, since then you inspect the actual queryset you will return, and thus avoid checking multiple quersets that are not used later in the process.

Comment: Nice answer,where do query_params method comes from?

Comment: @MikiBelavista: these are the `request.GET`s for Django's REST framework: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params

Comment: Thank you for the answer